# WMS Service is not displayed

Tags: wms, qgis-2

I try to display a wms-server in qgis. It serves several coordinate systems, but only few are working. Here is the link:
http://www.webatlasde.de/arcgis/services/Maps4BW/MapServer/WMSServer
For example EPSG:3857 is displayed, 31467 (which I need) is not
In ArcGis, the WMS is displayed correctly, so the server should be ok.
Can anyone confirm this problem or help me?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: i use QGIS 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use EPSG:31467 (DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 3) in QGIS 2.2.0.

[image: WMS-LGL Maps4BW Gauss-Kruger projection in QGIS]

I did this by using the Change button under Coordinate reference System (8 available), then in the Coordinate Reference System Selector used '31467' as a filter, selecting the result and clicking OK.

[image: Changing the projection of a WMS layer QGIS]

Comment: This also works for me in QGIS 1.8.0.  I think it would be odd for it to not work in 2.0.1 also, but it's not implausible.

Comment: Great, it's working with 2.2! But I had to setup the WMS again, with the old one (which has been transfered from 2.0.1) it was completely deformed. Thanks a lot